# Conditional color fill for areachart in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hello I'm trying to accomplish the following with highcharts:

-When x-value of series1 > x-value of series2, fill difference as color1
-When x-value of series1 < x-value of series2, fill difference as color2
-Series1 and 2 each have their own line color and points.

[Here is a drawing as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQQaX.jpg). Is this possible? I was using areachart as a start since it seems close to what I'm trig to do with filling color between two lines. I don't see anything in the documentation that would allow me to accomplish this, but perhaps there's some hack, or something I'm overlooking.

Any help is appreciated!